# Esri-arcgis request intercept based on wildcard route

Tags: reactjs, authorization, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to implement a MapLayer in my react application. The map is only accessible over a proxy which needs authentication to identify the users for each end every request.

To provide the token i added the following request interceptor to make sure all calls which access that backend would be expanded by the authorization. If i do it this way there is no header added to the requests.

```
esriConfig.request.interceptors.push({
  urls: ['backend/api/*'],
  before: async function (params: any) {
    params.requestOptions.headers = {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token),
    };
  },
});
```

If i remove the urls parameter so that all routes are extended with the token I'll recieve some cors errors because the esri package also makes some calls to another api where i get blocked because i'm sending an authorization header which is not expected.

Other api:
https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/portals/self?f=json&culture=de-de

How can i make sure only requests to my api will be extended with the autorization header?

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the regular expression, you need to escape the bar like this, `'backend\/api'` in order to capture it. Btw I don't think you need the `*`

Answer (score 0):

The urls property takes a String or RegExp or an array of those. See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-config.html#RequestInterceptor

You're specifyng the url as a string (not a proper RegEx).  You need to change

```
urls: ['backend/api/*'],
```

to

```
urls: [/backend\/api/],
```

or (without the array)

```
urls: /backend\/api/,
```